# SSIS For Each Loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a simple task but somehow getting bugged on it.

Through SSIS I want to empty 3 tables in my database. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to create a FEL and somwehere in the variable put the names of my two tables.
Then the loop will go and delete records from those two tables.

Tables are: Table1 Table2 and Table3.

Can you please give me a detailed step by step isntruction. Please don't paste links to other articles, as it might be even more confusing.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Need more details. How do we know what record to delete. You specify you want 3 tables emptied but your FEL is only dealing with 2 tables.

Comment: Basically: Delete from Table1,
Delete from Table2,
Delete from Table 3.

Comment: Do you consider that "detailed"?

Comment: Put another way, how is that not solved with an Execute SQL Task with `DELETE FROM Table1; DELETE FROM Table2; DELETE FROM Table3;`?

Comment: I will try it. But wanted to configure a FEL for it, as I might have much more tables to go through, lets say a 100.

Comment: How do you determine this list of tables? Is it hard coded? Is there a source for it? If there is, how do you access it

Comment: I want to try putting them into a variable for now in the FEL, hardcoded 3 tables. Later on it will ba a table that will contain tables to empty.

Comment: But if there is no other way we can put them in a table and get a SELECT into the FEL with the tables names. I just need instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a variable named `TableNames` of type *Object*
2. Create a variable named `TableName` of type *String*
3. Create a variable named `Query` of type *String*

   - Set the **EvaluateAsExpression** property to `True`
   - Set the **Expression** property to `"DELETE FROM " + @[User::TableName]`
4. Add an *Execute Sql Task* and double click to open the *Execute Sql Task Editor*

   - Make the following changes under the **General** settings

     - Set the **ResultSet** property to `Full Result Set`
     - Set the **SQLStatement** property to
       `select *
       from
       (
       select 'Table1' as t union
       select 'Table2' as t union
       select 'Table3' as t
       ) tables`
   - Make the following changes under the **Result Set** settings

     - Click Add button, and set the **Result Name** to `0` and the **Variable Name** to `User::TableNames`
5. Add a *Foreach Loop Container* and double click to open the *Foreach Loop Editor*

   - Make the following changes under the **Collection** settings

     - Set the **Enumerator** property to `Foreach ADO Enumerator`
     - Set the **ADO object source variable** to `User::TableNames`
   - Make the following changes under the **Variable Mappings** settings

     - Set the **Variable** to `User::TableName` and the **Index** to `0`
6. Add an *Execute Sql Task* inside the *Foreach Loop* and double click to open the *Execute Sql Task Editor*

   - Make the following changes under the **General** settings

     - Set the **SQLSourceType** property to `Variable`
     - Set the **SourceVariable** to `User::Query`